# Log And Mention User Who Created Role in server discord.py

Tags: discord.py

Hi I Try to make Logger Bot in discord.py
My Code:

```
@client.event
async def on_guild_role_create(guild, role):
    logs = await guild.audit_logs(limit=1, action=discord.AuditLogChanges.role_create).flatten()
    channel = guild.get_channel(channel_ID)
    logs = logs[0]
    if logs.target == role:
        #await channel.send(f'{logs.user} Created Role.')
```

Error I Got:

```
Ignoring exception in on_guild_role_create
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MY PC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MY PC\source\repos\Event\Event\Event.py", line 32, in on_guild_role_create
    logs = await guild.audit_logs(limit=1, action=discord.AuditLogChanges.role_create).flatten()
AttributeError: 'Role' object has no attribute 'audit_logs'
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`on_guild_role_create` only takes in one parameter, the role. We have to get the guild instance form the role.

```py
async def on_guild_role_create(role):
    guild = role.guild
    #other stuff here
```

### References:

- [role.guild](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_guild_role_create#discord.Role.guild)
- [on_guild_role_create](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_guild_role_create#discord.on_guild_role_create)